# TableCellRenderer strange behaviour java

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I'm trying to implement a custom TableCellRenderer on a jtable. the table is set to 100 rows and 100 columns. This table should contain all the glyphs for a specified font. My problem is that when the table is not fully complete with values, on the first column it puts the last value until it reaches the bottom of the table. Below i have the code for my custom renderer and a screenshot with the strange behaviour. Any help would be apreciated.

[image]

```
public class FontRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer
{
Font desired_font;
Object prec_value;

public FontRenderer(Font f)
{
    desired_font = f;
}

public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int rowIndex, int vColIndex)
{


    setOpaque(true);
    setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    if (isSelected)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            setText("");
        }
        else
        {
            setText(value.toString());
        }
        setFont(desired_font);
        setBackground(new Color(56, 195, 254));
    }
    if (value == null)
    {
        setText("");
    }
    else
    {
        if(value==null)
            table.setValueAt(null, rowIndex, vColIndex);
        else
        setText(value.toString());
            //table.setValueAt(value.toString(), rowIndex, vColIndex);

    }
    setFont(desired_font);

    return this;
}
}
```

Edit: Here is the code where I populate the table.

```
while (cnt_i < 100) {
    while (cnt_j < 100) {
        if (my_fnt.canDisplay((char) unicode_char) && glyph_count <= total_glyphs) {
            jTable1.setValueAt((char) unicode_char, cnt_i, cnt_j);
            cnt_j++;
            if (glyph_count == total_glyphs) {
                break;
            }
            glyph_count++;
        }
        unicode_char++;
    }
    cnt_i++;
    cnt_j = 0;
}
```

Solved it. Ty all. it was how i populated the table. the following code has the changes:

```
while (cnt_i < 100) {
    while (cnt_j < 100) {
        if (my_fnt.canDisplay((char) unicode_char) && glyph_count <= total_glyphs) {
            if (glyph_count == total_glyphs) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                jTable1.setValueAt((char) unicode_char, cnt_i, cnt_j);
                cnt_j++;
                glyph_count++;
            }
        }
        unicode_char++;
    }
    cnt_i++;
    cnt_j = 0;
}
```

Comment: even though your renderer is very redundant it does not seem to be the origin of your problem.

Comment: The data which is passed to your renderer is coming from the `TableModel`, so most likely that's where the problem is located. Please post that code instead of the rendering code

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be calling table.setValueAt (btw a renderer should not alter the table's content); So I guess the issue is in the way the table is populated

Comment: See also [`Font`Shower`](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/fontshower.html).

Answer (score 2):

1) there are about `Unicode` Chars, I think that is not job for `Renderer`

2) set [JTable#Font](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setFont%28java.awt.Font%29) for [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) rather that passing parameters for `Renderer`

3) use `prepareRenderer` if you want to change bunch of data on Runtime

4) most important would be to see how did you populate `JTable's` data and define/set for `Font(s)`

Answer (score 2):

I dont think that your problem is the CellRenderer ..

But I cleaned it up a bit for you

```
public class FontRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer
{
    Font desired_font;
    Object prec_value;

    public FontRenderer(Font f)
    {
        desired_font = f;
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int rowIndex, int vColIndex)
    {
        setOpaque(true);
        setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        setFont(desired_font);

        if (value == null)
        {
            setText("");
        }
        else
        {
            setText(value.toString());
        }

        if (isSelected)
        {
            setBackground(new Color(56, 195, 254));
        }

        //what was that for?
        //table.setValueAt(null, rowIndex, vColIndex);

        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As an aside, [`canDisplay(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#canDisplay%28int%29) may help determine if a particular code point has a glyph in a given `Font`. [`REPLACEMENT CHARACTER`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) is a convenient placeholder, and [`GlyphSet`](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons) is a related example.

Comment: while (cnt_i < 100)
        {
            while (cnt_j < 100)
            {
                if (my_fnt.canDisplay((char) unicode_char) && glyph_count <= total_glyphs)
                {
                    jTable1.setValueAt((char) unicode_char, cnt_i, cnt_j);
                    cnt_j++;
                    if (glyph_count == total_glyphs)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    glyph_count++;
                }
                unicode_char++;
            }
            cnt_i++;
            cnt_j = 0;
        }

Comment: sorry about this. it seems i cant answer my own question to be able to post formatted code until 8 hours have passed. I want to say that after i populate the table,if  i don't use the renderer, it populates just fine.

Comment: You can update your question, as I have done on your behalf. Of course, substituting your [sscce](http://sscce.org/) will be more effective. I'm guessing your implementation of `TableModel` is the problem. @mKorbel's and @rauschen's +1 answers are correct.

Comment: Thank you for the response trashgod. I looked through my code and i didn't implement any table model. my table uses the DefaultTableModel. The only thing i have done at that jtable is: jTable1.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF); and jTable1.setCellSelectionEnabled(true); now i'm really lost :(

Comment: `DefaultTableModel` _is_ your `TableModel` implementation.